# How to turn python turtle to specific rotation

Tags: python, rotation, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I want python turtle to turn to specific rotation because after drawing something random, I can't know what is turtle's rotation.
Is there a command that in I can type exact rotation that I want for turtle to turn?
(lt and rt can't help)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try [`seth`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.setheading). The turtle docs are not long--I suggest taking 5 minutes to skim them to save time in the future and develop a good sense of turtle's capabilities.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't thougth of that

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `t` is your turtle:

```
>>> t.setheading(new_absolute_angle)
>>> t.seth(new_absolute_angle)
```

Both work the same way.

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.setheading